How do we get $B(v_0,\pi(s)v_0)\neq 0,$ where $v_0\in V^{\psi}$ and $\pi(s)v_0\in V^{\psi^{-1}}$?
I was studying Lemma 1 in the D.Prasad's paper:
http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~dprasad/jalg.pdf
I just need more clarification.
Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $s$ be an element of the normalizer of $H$ such that $s^2$ is in the center of $G$. Let $\psi$ be a one dimensional representation of $H$ such that $\psi^{-1}(h)=\psi(shs^{-1})$ for all $h\in H$. Let $(\pi,V)$ be an irreducible self-dual representation of $G$ in which $\psi$ appears with multiplicity $1$ in $\pi|_{H}$. Let $B$ be a nonzero non-degenerate $G$-invariant bilinear form on $V$. Let $v_0 \in V$ be a nonzero vector such that $\pi(h)v_0=\psi(h)v_0$ for all $h\in H$. Note that $\pi(hs)v_0=\psi^{-1}(h)\pi(s)v_0$ for all $h\in H$. Assume $\psi^{-1}\neq \psi$. In this case, $v_0$ and $\pi(s)v_0$ are linearly independent vectors.

How can we conclude  that $B(v_0,\pi(s)v_0)\neq 0$?
If we don't assume $\psi^{-1}\neq \psi$, is $B(v_0,\pi(s)v_0)\neq 0$ still correct?

We see that $v_0\in V^{\psi}$ and $\pi(s)v_0\in V^{\psi^{-1}}$ where $V^{\psi}$ and $V^{\psi^{-1}}$ are the underlying vector spaces of the one dimensional representations $\psi$ and $\psi^{-1}$, respectively.
Thanks!
